# Faster scrolling/panning with large canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a page that is basically a large canvas with a lot of small icons connected with lines, and the user needs to be able to pan/zoom around. I've got everything working, but its very choppy. It seems that the repaining is the problem (if I remove the icons it becomes very smooth), but if I run Chrome's profiler, none of my functions are taking up any significant time at all.

Are there any better approaches to panning, without having to repaint everything? For instance in WinAPI, there was a function that scrolled the window content and only invalidated the thin region that just scrolled into view. Is there any way to do something similar in Javascript/canvas, since all I really need is to move the entire window?

I have tried making a giant canvas with everything pre-painted on it, that is then moved around with scrollLeft/scrollTop, but that takes *way* too much memory (what else should I expect from a 4000x4000 image) and makes zoom very slow instead.

Here's the page if anyone is interested, the code is pretty readable I hope:

http://poe.rivsoft.net/

Answer (score 2):

You will have to just put up with some slower parts. Consider creating dirty regions. These are areas that need to be redrawn when panning. Keep a back buffer the same size as the canvas. When panning copy from the back buffer to its self the area that remains visible and mark the newly visible area as dirty. Then every frame rerender only the dirty areas onto the back buffer. For zooming you can zoom the back buffer and re render when the user pauses or incrementally, this will create a pixelated view (like google maps) when zooming in or aliasing and dirty areas on the sides when zooming out, until you update it.

You can also limit the amount of dirty area redrawn each frame so maintaining a constant frame rate. It will not look as nice but it will improve the panning and zooming. On my machine it runs well (nice job BTW) so you may want to consider implementing optimisations only on machines that can not handle the load.

Also looking at the function `DrawNode` there is lots of room for optimisation as you have a lot of redundant code (especially once all assets have loaded)

This is just a suggestion as I do not know if nodes are unique or if the x, y coords change, but that can be accommodated as well. You have a lot of searching and checks that should be avoided. The use of strings instead of numbers or booleans to check for status and type is also slow.

```
  function DrawNode(ctx, node, x, y, active) {
      // Has this node got quick render information 
      if (node.qNode) {  
          // if so render the quick version
          var qn = node.qNode; // creating the var qn and then qn.? is quicker than access node.qNode.? 
          ctx.drawImage(qn.image, qn.coords.x, qn.coords.y, qn.coords.w, qn.coords.h, qn.x, qn.y, qn.size, qn.size);
          return;
      }
      var type = NodeTypes[node.type];
      var frameType = "frame" + (active ? "Active" : "Inactive");  // active should be a boolean
      if (type && type.size && node.type !== "jewel") { // should be !node.isJewel with isJewwl a boolean
          var spriteType = node.type;
          if (node.type !== "mastery") // Should be boolean
              spriteType += (active ? "Active" : "Inactive");
          var sprites = SkillTree.skillSprites[spriteType][3];
          var image = GetImage("Assets/" + sprites.filename);
          var coords = sprites.coords[node.icon];
          if (image && image.loaded && coords) {
              ctx.drawImage(image, coords.x, coords.y, coords.w, coords.h,
                  x - type.size * 0.5, y - type.size * 0.5, type.size, type.size);

              // add the information to quickly render the node next time. 
              // You may want to add sub objects for Mastery Active,inactive
              node.qNode = {
                  image : image,
                  coords : coords,
                  x : x - type.size * 0.5,
                  y : y - type - sise * 0.5,
                  size : type.size
              }

          } else if (!image || !image.loaded) {
              return false;
          }
      }
      // same deal for the other type.
  }
```

When optimising you start at the slowest point and make that code as efficient as possible, then work your way out. It is well written code but it has no eye for speed so I would say there is lots more room for improvement in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I know the logic in the rendering code itself could be faster, but as I said, the profiler says that its barely taking any time, and the real time spender seems to be in the graphics API or something. The things you suggest to make booleans come from JSON data that I have no control over. I could preprocess it to turn the strings into bools but I'm not sure if its worth the hassle.  However, I do like the backbuffer suggestion. I'll experiment with it, hope it doesn't increase the memory use too much as that's something I've been trying to keep low.

Comment: Actually, it seems to only be a problem in Chrome. Firefox and even other chromium-based browsers have no issue with this page. *confused*

Comment: @riv For a couple of months Chrome has been lagging behind Firefox and Edge when it comes to rendering. I will have a look at the profiler on your page when I get a chance and see if anything obvious sticks out.